# Firestore Timestamp

Tags: firebase, timestamp, firestore

Estou fazendo um programa com o *Firestore* de uma ficha de cadastro.

Quando a data é salva no banco de dados, ela é salva como Timestamp (Por exemplo: Timestamp(seconds=149914800, nanoseconds=0)), porém quando eu abro a aba de edição da ficha, a data vem em forma de *Timestamp*, logo **preciso fazer a conversão para uma data normal**, pesquisei na documentação do *Firestore* e vi a função `toDate()` (que converte o *Timestamp* para uma data), mas quando fui usá-la, o console me traz o seguinte erro:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: data_nasc_.toDate is not a function

Queria saber como solucioná-lo ou então uma outra forma de fazer essa conversão.

```
firebase.firestore().collection("usuario").doc(ocorrencia).get().then(usuario => {  

    data_nasc_ = usuario.data().Data_Nascimento.toDate();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia, aparentemente Data_Nascimento.toDate(); está certo, pelo erro, você está tentando dar um toDate() de novo no data_nasc_.toDate, o data_nasc_ já é uma data

Comment: boa tarde esqueci de ver as respostas, acontece que os dados foram gravados no database sendo uma string e nela vinha como Timestamp(seconds=149914800, nanoseconds=0), mas não era um Timestamp real do Firebase, mudamos como a data foi gravada e funcionou a função toDate normalmente